# Magento 2: AJAX / PHP files Knockout uses for Checkout

Tags: magento2, php, checkout, ajax, knockoutjs

Anyone know what PHP files, or the AJAX scripts, Knockout uses to pull the product data from the database?

Basically, I'm trying to work out how Knockout knows how much product X and product Y are.

**Update**:
On Checkout, the Summary section displays the cart's contents – the name and qty of each product. I would like to extend this to include more product data – size attribute / color attribute etc.

If someone could point me in the direction in which Knockout is grabbing the name and qty, I'll be able to request further data from the database.

Comment: In what context?

Comment: Can you add more info?

Comment: More info added. Thank you for any help you might be able to give.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly review below files

1) Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider.php

2) vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\onepage.phtml

3) vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\cart\item\default.phtml

4) vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

5) vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers.xml

6) vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

7) vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\summary\item\details.js

8) vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html